# docker load : no space left on device

Tags: docker

I am using linux RedHat 7.

I have no options to change the configuration of my server.

When I run

```
docker load -i images.tar 

Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /665b3743d81d9b5952e83a3f55aec18bd8eb082696215e534fa1da6247e99855/layer.tar: no space left on device
```

There is very little space on the `/` mount, but I have lots available in `/apps`

How do I tell docker to use my `/apps` mount when I run `docker load`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

Basically move the docker folder in the /var/lib folder to the apps folder, then create a sym link to it back in the /var/lib folder

```
sudo mv /var/lib/docker /apps/docker
ln -s /apps/docker /var/lib/docker
```